# 3 I'm performing simple CRUD operations using Servlet and JSP. Following example is Shown Below:

Tags: java, html, jsp, jdbc

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<style>
body
{
    form-align:center;
}
</style>
<body>
<form action="studentDB" method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <th><h2>Student Information</h2></th>
        <tr>
            <td><b>StudentID:</b><input type="text" name="sid" placeholder="Enter your ID"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Student Name:</b><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Student Address:</b><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter your Address"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
    <p><a href="viewdata">View Student Data</a></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*This is `HTML`*

**DbConnection.java**

```
package pack;
import java.sql.*;

public class DbConnection
{
    private static Connection con;
    
    
    static
    {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","kera_@123");
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
        public static Connection getConnection()
        {
            return con;
        }
        
    
    
}
```

*In DbConnection.java i've created a static Connection which is accessing in other servlet*

**StudentDB.java**

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/studentDB")
public class studentDB extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
  
    public studentDB() 
{
        super();
       
    }

    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            Connection con=DbConnection.getConnection();
            String SID=request.getParameter("sid");
            String Name=request.getParameter("name");
            String Address=request.getParameter("address");
            if(SID=="")
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
                rd.include(request, response);
                out.println("<font color=red><h2>Insert Your ID Please</h2></font>");
                
            }
            else
            {
                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into student values(?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, SID);
                ps.setString(2,Name);
                ps.setString(3, Address);
                int row=ps.executeUpdate();
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
                rd.include(request, response);
                out.println("<font color=green><b>Record Updated Successfully.</b></font>");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        
        
    }

    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
        
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

*In StudentDB.java i've inserted my data into table name :student*

**viewdata.java**

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class viewdata
 */
@WebServlet("/viewdata")
public class viewdata extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public viewdata() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {       
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            Connection con=DbConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from student");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            out.println("<table border=1>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td><b>StudentID</td></b>");
            out.println("<td><b>StudentName</b></td>");
            out.println("<td><b>StudentAddress</b></td>");
            out.println("<td><b>Edit</b></td>");
            out.println("<td><b>Delete</b></td>");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("studentid")+"</td>");
                out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("studentname")+"</td>");
                out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("studentaddress")+"</td>");
                
                out.println("<td>"+"<a href=edit?studentid="+rs.getString("studentid")+">Edit</a>"  + "</td>");
                
                out.println("<td>"+"<a href=delete?studentid="+rs.getString("studentid")+">Delete</a>"  + "</td>");
                
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table");
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

*From this viewdata.java i can view all  the data which i've inserted in my table*

**edit.java**

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class edit
 */
@WebServlet("/edit")
public class edit extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public edit() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            Connection con=DbConnection.getConnection();
            String SID=request.getParameter("sid");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from student where studentid=?");
            ps.setString(1, SID);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
             System.out.println("Contents of the first record: ");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                out.println("<h2>Update Employee</h2>");
                
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    }

}
```

** In edit.java i'm unable to edit my data i.e " `out.println("<h2>Update Employee</h2>");` is not working here but displaying in console while running in server. `System.out.println("Contents of the first record: ");` **

**delete.java**

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class delete
 */
@WebServlet("/delete")
public class delete extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public delete() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            Connection con=DbConnection.getConnection();
            String SID=request.getParameter("sid");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from student where StudentID=?");
            ps.setString(1, SID);
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Record is deleted");
            out.println("<font color=green><b>Successfully Deleted!!!</b></font>");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        
        
    }

}
```

*From delete.java i'm unable to delete the records but in console it displays message that `System.out.println("Record is deleted");` and when i deploy this one into server it displays messages `out.println("<font color=green><b>Successfully Deleted!!!</b></font>");` but when i refresh the pages it restores back rather than deleting the data from student table.

Comment: You've provided a *huge* amount of code here, but I suspect very little of it is actually relevant to the problem. Have you tried running your deletion code from a simple console application? Does that manage to delete the record successfully? When you say in the question "it restores back" what exactly do you mean? It will be much, much easier to help you if you provide a [mcve]. (I'd also very strongly advise you to start following Java naming conventions.)

Comment: The major problem is I'm unable to delete the data from my table name: student. "it restores back" means It displays in console that record is deleted but when i refresh the page the data remains constant. I think  'PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from student where StudentID=?");  this is SQL command is not working here..

Comment: Right - so that sounds like something you could demonstrate with a console application which *just* tries to delete the record. The JSP and HTML is entirely irrelevant - so it would be good to remove it from the problem.